# ModelBinder validation breaks on getter using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I've ran across a problem which seems to be related to reflection and model binder validation, and `FormatterParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(..)` in particular, and though I can use a Method to do what I want I would prefer it if I could use a Property.

Here I'm looking for some insight into the model binder validation process, why I am unable to do what I want and how I can fix the problem, or get around it.

**The setup**

```
public class ModelBindingValidationBreaker
{
    public ModelBindingValidationBreaker()
    {
        Properties = new List<string>();
    }

    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Properties { get; set; }

    /*// Uncomment to break the model binder validation!
    public IList<PropertyInfo> PropertyInfos
    {
        get
        {
            return GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(pi => Properties.Contains(pi.Name))
                .ToList();
        }
    }//*/

    public IList<PropertyInfo> GetPropertyInfos()
    {
        return GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(pi => Properties.Contains(pi.Name))
            .ToList();
    }

    public IList<int> LetterCounts
    {
        get
        {
            return Properties.Select(p => p.Length).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

And a controller with a post action defined like this

```
public void Post(ModelBindingValidationBreaker breaker){...}
```

Call it with this kind of json:

```
{
    "Properties": [
        "A"
    ],
    "A": 1,
    "B": 2
}
```

If you step into the action you can see that the breaker is correctly instantiated and you can call `GetPropertyInfos()` without any issue.

**How it breaks**

However, if you uncomment the PropertyInfos property, the model binder validation breaks. I added a simple tracer to figure this out. It shows the following relevant output:

```
System.Web.Http.Action: ApiControllerActionSelector;SelectAction;Selected action 'Post(ModelBindingValidationBreaker breaker)'
System.Web.Http.ModelBinding: HttpActionBinding;ExecuteBindingAsync;
System.Web.Http.ModelBinding: FormatterParameterBinding;ExecuteBindingAsync;Binding parameter 'breaker'
System.Net.Http.Formatting: JsonMediaTypeFormatter;ReadFromStreamAsync;Type='ModelBindingValidationBreaker', content-type='application/json'
System.Net.Http.Formatting: JsonMediaTypeFormatter;ReadFromStreamAsync;Value read='OverPostCount.Models.ModelBindingValidationBreaker'
System.Web.Http.ModelBinding: FormatterParameterBinding;ExecuteBindingAsync;
System.Web.Http.ModelBinding: HttpActionBinding;ExecuteBindingAsync;
System.Web.Http.Controllers: CustomController;ExecuteAsync;
System.Net.Http.Formatting: DefaultContentNegotiator;Negotiate;Type='HttpError', formatters=[JsonMediaTypeFormatterTracer, FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatterTracer, FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatterTracer]
```

Which contains this line instead, when you exclude the offending get_PropertyInfos:

```
System.Web.Http.ModelBinding: FormatterParameterBinding;ExecuteBindingAsync;Parameter 'breaker' bound to the value 'OverPostCount.Models.ModelBindingValidationBreaker'
```

Adding `DataContract`, and related attributes like `[IgnoreDataMember]` on Properties does not fix the problem. Neither does `[Bind(Exclude="Properties")]` from the mvc namespace. Linq does not seem to be the problem, since `LetterCount` does not break the model binder validation.

**My questions**

1. Why does the PropertyInfos getter break the model binder validator?
2. Is this a bug in the Asp.NET web-api?
3. Is there a way to prevent this breakage through attributes, a custom model binder validator, service or similar?

Basically I don't want to turn off model binding validation for the whole class or controller, but if I could turn it off for the Properties property, that would be great!

Comment: I wonder why I even bother asking non-trivial questions on SO. People just want to grind points and don't really care about helping anyhow it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule you should avoid using complex classes like PropertyInfos that have properties with other complex types...in classes used for model binding, but you should use just simple classes that contains JUST THE PROPERTIES you need for the model binding process, moreover the whole  object graph should contain no loops. Model binding process analyze the type of properties for different purposes (validation attributes, etc.) an i may recusrively analyze the sub-properties of contained in the type of eac property...so complex .net classes containing loops and a lot of other .net types may break it.
Try making the property PropertyInfos internal or turn it into a method so it shgould not be processed, by any model binder component.

Comment: That's very unsatisfying to be honest. What I'm hearing is that I should only use dumb classes, structs really, for all my model binding, meaning for all my models. Meaning I'm being forced to use dumb DTO's. That may be best pracitice and recommended. But what if that doesn't fit my scenario? C# is an oo language and I should be allowed to bind to smart classes with complex properties. The least they could offer is a way to disable model binding validation for specific properties through attributes, for rebels like me.

Comment: What exactly is it the model binder is doing that requires it to go into my getter and what causes it to break? When I have IgnoreDataMemberAttribute on it, it's not being bound so it shouldn't be validated, and the code shouldn't break. Looks unfinished to me.

Comment: you are looking at the problem from the wrong perpspective. You are not limited to use struct! What is not recommended is using complex business classes in the presntation layer. In the presentation layer you work with viewmodels, not with business classes. You are free to add complkexity that you need in the presentation layer. The model binding process involve a tree of objects(subobjects contained in properties). Loops are not allowed since all algorithms are not able to recognize to properties point to the same object and duplicate it.

Comment: The model binding and validation algorithms explore recursively the object tree to find validation attributes and metadata. This means that if you use properties whose datatype is a complex system type with hundreds of properties, that complex datatype is explored recursively with all its properties...and the probability that it contains loops or that you go into a security issue (if you dont run with full thrust) is almost 100%

Comment: Ignore attributes should affect just the serialization deserialization stage, not the validation.

Comment: I'm not using view-models, since this is for a rest api. I know I'm not limited to structs, but effectively that's the limitation. Furthermore loops is supported by json.NET even if it isn't by the xml-formatter, so by removing the xml-formatter I should even be able to have loops in my object graph (even if that's not what I'm after here). But you are probably right that there's something important I'm missing. Like what exactly the job of the model binder validation is. I still feel I should be able to add properties that I should be able to exclude from the validation explicitly.

Comment: After all.. this is a "compute-property" and it shouldn't ever need to be validated.

Comment: At best of my knowledge the only way to exclude a property from validation (when  validation is on) is by declaring it not public. The point is that Validation is not a property level concept but a whole object concept, so it make sense just to validate the whole object. Now if the value of your get only property depends on the state of the object there is no reason to skip validation of that property. On the contrary if the property doesnt depend on the state of the object you can skip validation..but in this case you can declare the property as static and in this case it is not validated

Comment: Now the point is that your object contains both "normal" data, and "metadata" properties (your Properties)...and probably you need just to validate the "normal data" part of your object, since you use metadata just to manage the way the object is processed.

Comment: You can achieve this by putting all metadatas into an object that Implemments an Interface, say IMetadata. So you can put it into a an object property declared as IMetadata. IMetadata doesnt expose "Properties" or "PropertyInfos", that maybe exposed by another interface implemented by the same object... This should solve the general problem of hiding metadata related properties to validation, not only in this object but in the whole application.

Comment: I don't follow your implementation recipie. Are you saying I add a property Meta of type IMetadata onto ModelBindingValidationBreaker, and implement that on a class Metadata. Then IMetadata doesn't expose the PropertyInfos property which Metadata implements. That would mean I have to cast the Meta property to Metadata to access my PropertyInfos. That's adding code-smell and annoyance. ;) Did I read you wrong?

Comment: What I don't understand is, why the resistance against the idea of adding an attribute to the framework to exclude certain compute-type, or meta-data like properties from the model binder validation? It seems like a usefull and reasonable thing to add, don't you think? (Thanks for the effort btw.)

Comment: I dont suggested to put just the PropertyInfos property into the Metadata class but all metadata related methods, fields and properties. Then you write some specilized classes to handle the whole operations on the metadata contained in a class. Not just reading the PropertyInfos value, but the whole operations. This way you increase the moldularity of your application by fatoring out all metadata processing in specialized modules. This way you are free to change the way you handle metadata by just changing the Metadata class and the specialized classes with no need to modify other parts.

Comment: In other terms my recipie is not a dirty trick but I clean way to separate into differnt modules the the class that define the contract between client and server of your rest service and other parts that you need just to perform sever side processing that the client doesnt need to know of. In your case, since this server processing is just a metadata processing you can keep all these infos in the same class the metadata refers to, instead of using two separate classes (one class that define the contract and another version of it to be used as business class).

Comment: In more complex cases you wiull need to define a class whose purpose is just the one of defining the interface between client and another class to be used to perform server side processing. In Wcf services you can define the interface betwee server and client by using the variou DataContract, DataMember, Ignore, etc attributes...but with ApiController this is difficult because the attributes are tied to the formatter you use, and the previus attributes are used just by the DataContract formatter. In particular they are not used by the Validation provider, and by other processors you might add

Comment: Defining and Ignore attribute just for the Validation provider would not solve the problem since each module has its own attributes and you might change the the modules you are using during the lifetime of the application. This means that to be sure that aproperty is not processed by any module you would be forced to add a lot of different Ingnore attributes on it. So better to hide completely that property or by defining another parallel communication-only class or behind some interface, or also behind an internal keyword.

Comment: This is a peculiarity of just the Api Controller binding process, that is composed by several customizable modules, instead of being an unique chunk of software as the standard Mvc ModelBinder.