# How to bind parameter when it has reference to itself?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, post, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Here is a problem.
We have a simple web api controller with one class in it

```
public class CheckApiController : ApiController
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SomeString { get; set; }
        /*public Test ComplexType
        {
            get
            {
                return new Test()
                {
                    SomeString = "wtf"
                };
            }
        }*/
    }
    public List<Test> Get()
    {
        return new List<Test>(){
            new Test(){Id = 1,SomeString = "1st string"},
            new Test(){Id=2,SomeString = "2nd string"}
        };
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Test testclass)
    {
        //do something
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        return response;
    }
}
```

When I check in fiddler `Get` and `Post` methods everything is OK. But when i uncomment the property `ComplexType` in `Test` and try again `POST` method will respond with huge 500 internal server error:

*Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on the stack using too much stack space.*

So its simple StackOverflow exception. So why this error happens with field that has no setter or how can i ignore it in binding?

Comment: Are you doing something else in the Post method?

Comment: Yes. But it doesnt matter, bcos the debugger doesnt get in this method, and responce returns with internal server error. Did u tried that code at your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about whats happening here. When you POST the object WebApi is building your Test class to build it it gets the ComplexType, which returns a new Test, which gets ComplexType, which returns a new Test and so on until you run out of stack.

Having any logic in you Model you send to/from your Api is generally not a great idea. Here is some info on DTOs, which explains why http://www.servicedesignpatterns.com/requestandresponsemanagement/datatransferobject

Id Recommend amending your Test class to look like:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
    public Test ComplexType { get; set; }
}
```

And then assigning the 'SomeString' value afterwards.

Comment: Ok. I understand it. But why behavior of `POST` request in usual controller (MVC) doesnt throw this error? And i dont know why it is  call 'get' while the purpose is to 'set' properties.

Comment: It's all just a part of the model binding process. The Model binder will inspect and analyse the objects to check they fit behind the scenes. I found this post which is similar to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11860763/692830